# Turning a commented URL into a clickable link in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I've created a site with commenting functionality in rails but whenever a user types in a link, it is unclickable and I have to copy and paste it into the browser.  Are there any simple fixes for this?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [rails_autolink](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails_autolink) gem, since the autolink functionality was removed from Rails in 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Before Rails 3.1, you can use a helper method in `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` called `auto_link` to achieve this.

See this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link

It was removed in Rails 3.1: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html